# Preferred way of handling bibliography in academic writing

Tags: technique, academic-writing, citations, software, tools

I write a B.Sc. thesis in google docs. They don't have a good way for references. They have something called citations which is not good for thesis. I've done my bibliography the IEEE way (IIUC) and use brackets like [x] for a reference from the bibliography.

Example

> A security problem with hardware peripherals is that an operating
>   system usually trusts a connected hardware peripheral that in practice
>   can be used for abuse such as data theft or computer hijacking [7].

Now it is cumbersome to change the whole list if I insert an alphabetical reference in the middle or in the beginning, then I must rearrange all my references in the whole text and there is no automation in google docs to do it. Should I change to another system that can handle references or is there any good way to achieve what I'm trying to do?

Comment: It's not Google Docs, but it's equally simple. Do you know anything about markdown? If you know Github (and it sounds like you might) it uses markdown for readme docs and the like. But markdown can do more than that. It can handle references! And it can automate them for you. There are lots of markdown editors.

Comment: @russellmania Cool, I can try that.

Answer (score 2):

Google Docs does not directly support endnotes or alternate styles of citation, but there are multiple free Add-ons that might help, such as PaperPile, EasyBib, ProQuest RefWorks, F1000, and colwiz, [according to a Google Docs volunteer and mentor on the Google Docs forum](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/docs/YYOVGKspCj0).

I looked at the web page for a few of these and they do look promising. It depends on how much of their functionality is accessible and a Google Docs Add-on.